# Reference sought for Conway's observation on stable matchings

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, lattice-theory, matching-theory

Looking for a reference on the observation that the set of [stable matchings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stable_marriage_problem) form a [distributive lattice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_of_stable_matchings). This is attributed to Conway by Knuth in "Marriages Stables" but I would like an explicit reference if possible, likely a text book. An undergrad student needs it for his bibliography in a term paper.

Comment: I have three papers on stable matchings before me. All of them refer to Knuth, adding "attributed to Conway" but not giving a citation. Maybe Conway never cared to write up his result?

Comment: also, I think Knuth is extra meticulous in chasing down bibliographic references---so chances are slim that you will get a more exact citation.

Answer (score 5):

**strong text**

Conway discovered it when visiting Montreal contemporaneously to Knuth's
lectures on the marriage problem. These lectures are in print, published by Centre de
Recherche Math of Universite de Montreal.